# Referencing a textview from a custom method in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm starting out with Java, so please bear with me. So the main point of this part of code is when the user enters the monthly budget, it should get a call to the TextWatcher and then return the daily budget to the BudgetSettingActivity, where it sets the value to the DailyBudgetView TextView. Now, the question is, how do I get a reference to that view? With the current code my application crashes and once I try to debug it I see, that it crashes when I try to get the reference to the DailyBudgetView.

Here is the BudgetSettingActivity class:

```
package nick.mirosh.budgetplanner;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BudgetSettingsActivity extends Activity {

    double dailyBudget;
    String[] monthNames = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
            "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November",
            "December" };
    TextView dailyBudgetView;

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_budget_settings);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        TextView monthlyBudget = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.monthlyBudget);
        monthlyBudget.setHint("Set the budget for " + monthNames[month]);
        monthlyBudget.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new DecimalDigits(9, 2) });
        monthlyBudget.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(
                monthlyBudget));

        TextView dailyBudgetView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dailyBudget);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.budget_settings, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void setDailyBudget(double amount) {

        dailyBudget = amount;

        TextView dailyBudgetView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dailyBudget);
        dailyBudgetView.setText(dailyBudget + "");
    }

}
```

here is the GenericTextWatcher class

```
package nick.mirosh.budgetplanner;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;

public class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    BudgetSettingsActivity activity = new BudgetSettingsActivity();

    private View view;

    public GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1,
            int i2) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        String text = editable.toString();
        double dailyBudget = Double.parseDouble(text) / 30.0;

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.monthlyBudget:

            activity.setDailyBudget(dailyBudget);
        }
    }
}
```

here is my XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".BudgetSettingsActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/monthlyBudget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dailyBudget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is log cat:

```
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/InputEventSender(3111): Exception dispatching finished signal.
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at nick.mirosh.budgetplanner.BudgetSettingsActivity.setDailyBudget(BudgetSettingsActivity.java:48)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at nick.mirosh.budgetplanner.GenericTextWatcher.afterTextChanged(GenericTextWatcher.java:32)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7334)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:9087)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5464)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5283)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2623)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7343)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1933)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1408)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2384)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3791)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3774)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3516)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3666)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:1982)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1698)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1689)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:1959)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3111):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 07:53:46.398: D/AndroidRuntime(3111): Shutting down VM
04-19 07:53:46.398: W/dalvikvm(3111): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2ed7648)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at nick.mirosh.budgetplanner.BudgetSettingsActivity.setDailyBudget(BudgetSettingsActivity.java:48)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at nick.mirosh.budgetplanner.GenericTextWatcher.afterTextChanged(GenericTextWatcher.java:32)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7334)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:9087)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5464)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5283)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2623)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7343)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1933)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1408)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2384)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3791)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3774)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3516)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3666)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:1982)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1698)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1689)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:1959)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-19 07:53:46.398: E/AndroidRuntime(3111):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main
04-19 07:53:46.418: D/dalvikvm(3111): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 252K, 13% free 2715K/3096K, paused 12ms, total 17ms
```

Comment: did you solved it??

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView monthlyBudget = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.monthlyBudget);
```

you are casting TextView to EditText.
Change it to:

```
TextView monthlyBudget = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.monthlyBudget);
```

Also you have defined

`TextView dailyBudgetView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dailyBudget);` twice.
One within onCreate() and other within setDailyBudget(double amount).Delete the second one.It should work.

Comment: @programmingNoob Follow what kgandroid suggested.  I guess this should solve your problem and if problem still persists then post your log along with code. It will help understand better.